# SSRS Go to URL in new Tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, reporting-services

I have several reports with links to sub reports that open in new windows.  These worked fine in IE, but only work in Chrome if you hold the Ctrl key. Chrome is our new default browser.  Is there a way around this?  Based on the posts I've read, I would have to download the IE Tab addin or update Chrome settings.  I'm looking for something that can be done in the URL expression as I'm not able to download addins or update end user Chrome settings.

Current code is using "JavaScript(window.open method.  Chrome does not support JavaScript.

Thank you

Comment: If I remember correct, SSRS reports have inbuilt toolbar to download report in various format. Are you doing server side download?

Comment: Also, its a rare occasion when chrome does not support JS. Can you please share the code you are trying?

Comment: Perhaps this article may give you some insight.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b01776d9-56be-453d-bde8-718299bb1660/problem-with-opening-of-sql-server-reports-in-google-chrome?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I'm using this code (field names changed) which works if I hold the Ctrl key in Chrome.  I am trying to find something that opens the url in a new tab without holding the Ctrl key.

=iif(Sum(Fields!FieldName.Value) = 0,""
,"javascript:void(window.open('http://ServerName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fFolderName%2fReportName&Param1=" & Fields!Param1.Value & "&Param2="& Fields!Param2.Value & "','_blank'))")

The article has the same issue but I don't know how to implement the fix recommended:   &rs:Format=HTML4.0&rs:Command=Render

Comment: Downloading to various formats from the main report works, it is the url to the subreport where I am having trouble...

Comment: Opening new a tab instead of a new window is a browser setting in IE, too.